# How can an #if directive have a constexpr input in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

Is there a way to define a `constexpr` before an `#if` compiler directive as its input?
In other words, can `#if` have inputs from `constexpr`? If not, does it mean `#if` directive is evaluated before the `constexpr`?

```
constexpr int enable_debug = true;

#if (enable_debug)
std::string debug_logs;
#endif
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
   f(i);
   #if (enable_debug)
   debug_logs += std::to_string(i);
   #endif
}
#if (enable_debug)
std::court << debug_logs;
#endif
```

This question has two objectives:

- Is "directive time" or  "pragma time" earlier than compile time?
- I want to build some code only conditionally, but the code defined a variable, so I cannot use `if constexpr()`.

Comment: A "pragma" is a `#pragma`. `#if` is a preprocessing directive.

Comment: no, the preprocessor runs before anything else and doesn't understand c++ at all. try `if constexpr`

Comment: This question clearly suffers from [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to achieve? What is your actual goal? I'm guessing you should use some logger library.

Comment: @Marek, I want to build some code only conditionally, but the code defined a variable, so I cannot use `if constexpr()`. I will add it.

Comment: @Marek, but more specifically, I want to make sure it is not possible to refer to a `constexp` by a directive, since it is done before as @Sneftel answered. So I got my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. Preprocessor commands are applied in an earlier phase of translation than the evaluation (or even full parsing) of variable definitions. `#if` can do normal integer arithmetic and comparisons, and can expand preprocessor macros which were created with `#define`, but it cannot inspect non-preprocessor code.

You'll either need to make `enable_debug` a preprocessor macro, or change from preprocessor conditionals to `if` or `if constexpr` (which, of course, have their own limitations).

Comment: This is the clarification what I needed.